# Define \newtheorem environment using jheppub.styt

Tags: environments, newtheorem

I am using the [JHEP style](https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP_TeXclass.jsp) for writing a paper in latex. I would like to define new theorem\definition... environments, for example

```
\newtheorem{thr}{\color{Blue} Theorem}\numberwithin{thr}{section}
```

However, it seems that this specific style does not allow the definition of such environments. I am wondering whether there is any bypass for this problem.

Comment: If I add `\usepackage{xcolor}` and `\newtheorem{thr}{\textcolor{blue}{Theorem}}[section]` to the provided example file, there is no problem at all.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much, it works perfectly.

Comment: @egreg  Just a point. When I used `\textcolor{blue}{Theorem}` I get something that like Theorem 1.1 in which only the word Theorem is blue. When I use just `\color{...}`, the number appears in blue as well.

Comment: Well, yes, but it's by chance.

Comment: i am facing the warning in this style as "option pagecolour is not available anymore"How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from their package, just define your new theorem and use it as follows. Note that `\textcolor{blue}{Theorem}` is better than `{\color{blue} Theorem}` and note also the `blue` with lowercase `b`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1 % if your are submitting a pdflatex (i.e. if you have
             % images in pdf, png or jpg format)

\usepackage{jheppub} % for details on the use of the package, please
                     % see the JHEP-author-manual
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % if needed

\title{\boldmath A title with some math: $x=1$}

% more complex case: 4 authors, 3 institutions, 2 footnotes
\author[a,b,1]{F. Irst,\note{Corresponding author.}}
\author[c]{S. Econd,}
\author[a,2]{T. Hird\note{Also at Some University.}}
\author[a,2]{and Fourth}

% The "\note" macro will give a warning: "Ignoring empty anchor..."
% you can safely ignore it.

\affiliation[a]{One University,\\some-street, Country}
\affiliation[b]{Another University,\\different-address, Country}
\affiliation[c]{A School for Advanced Studies,\\some-location, Country}

% e-mail addresses: one for each author, in the same order as the authors
\emailAdd{first@one.univ}
\emailAdd{second@asas.edu}
\emailAdd{third@one.univ}
\emailAdd{fourth@one.univ}

\newtheorem{thr}{\color{blue} Theorem} \numberwithin{thr}{section}

\abstract{Abstract...}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\flushbottom

\section{Some examples and best-practices}
\label{sec:intro}

\begin{thr}
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ 
is a continuous function.
\end{thr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\color{blue} Theorem` is not really correct: `\textcolor{blue}{Theorem}` is right.

Comment: Yes, `\textcolor{blue}{Theorem}` is better, but I left the OP code for easy comparison with his/her non-working code.

Comment: Also `\numberwithin{thr}{section}` is dubious: it's much simpler to use the proper syntax: `\newtheorem{\textcolor{blue}{Theorem}}[section]`.